# Cypress not able to execute my test on proxy

Tags: cypress

I am using Cypress 12.3.0
I want to run a cypress test which requires a proxy to visit that url. But I am not able to visit the url.
What I have tried till now-

1. I have a windows system. So I have tried set "http_proxy":"http://some_proxy:8080"
2. I also set the proxy in cypress.config.js env { http_proxy:"http://some_proxy:8080" }. I have also validated in my test case like cy.log(Cypress.env('http_proxy')) - it is returning the right thing, but i think it is not applying the proxy.

Right now in cypress [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tdDJ.png)

I am new in cypress and I want to add one more point like all the websites which are on company network are accessible but I want to add a proxy for visiting the url. Manually I will able to do this, but by cypress I am facing issues.

Comment: Can you specify exactly how you're setting the proxy? Cypress has some docs for setting the proxy, and their recommendation would be `setx HTTP_PROXY=http://some_proxy:8080`. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration#Set-a-proxy-on-Windows

Comment: Actually I tried this, setx HTTP_PROXY http://some_proxy:8080 but still chrome browser didnt recogonized it. In my local the proxy is set but with cypress it is not detecting the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue in my initial days with Cypress. I resolved it by these four commands:

`$env:HTTP_PROXY = "http://<username>:<password>@<domain>:80/"`

`setx HTTP_PROXY http://<username>:<password>@<domain>:80/`

`npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@domain:80`

`npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@domain:80`

After running these four commands with your proxy details, open the cypress runner and check the proxy details are configured with what you have provided. Give a try and comment back whether it worked or not.